# In karyoploteR, how can I color specific cytobands based on their names?

Tags: r, plot, colors

I would like to ask for some help in using karyoploteR.

I am trying to plot some custom genomes with custom cytobands. I want to color each region based on the names. Unfortunately, I was not successful after trying to parse a custom table that would serve as a dictionary.

Here is my sample custom genome.

```
custom.genome <- data.frame(c(name,start,end), c(g1,1,2000), c(g2,1500), c(g3,1,5000))
```

My custom cytobands is defined in this table

```
custom.cytobands <- data.frame(c(chr,start,end,name,gieStain), c(g1,25,700,kap1,*blank), c(g1,1500,1756,lys3,*blank), c(g2,756,1156,kap1,*blank), c(g3,4522,4852,lys3,*blank))
```

I tried making a dataframe that would assign a particular color to a particular cytoband

```
color.table <- data.frame(c(kap1,red), c(lys3,blue))
```

What I have tried so far:

(1) Calling kpAddCytobands
`kpAddCytobands(kp, color.table = color.table)`

(2)Assigning colors
`getCytobandColors(color.schema="biovizbase")`

I am a little rusty in R and could not quite wrap my head around this particular package.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might not like this suggestion, but if you are looking for more customisation than what Cytobands allows, you might consider using ggplot2. Cytobands is just a wrapper function, so it will limit what you can customise.

Comment: @Earlien thank you very much for the suggestion. It do really seems like that karyoploteR is not the appropriate package for what I am trying to achieve, I'll try to play around ggplot2 instead. thanks for the suggestion,